# Combinatorial representation of function

Tags: co.combinatorics, partitions, algebraic-combinatorics

Let $f(x, y, z)$ is the number of distinct ways of representing $x$ as a sum of at most $y$ positive integers that are all smaller or equal to $z$.  Moreover, If $yz < x$, then the function gives 0.
The function can be defined in one of the following equivalent ways.

- The number $f(x,y,z)$.
- The number of all partitions     (meaning: without considering the ordering)
  $x = a_1 + \ldots + a_y$,     where $a_i \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$       and $a_i \leq z$ for all $i$.
- The sum over the number of all partitions     $x = a_1 + \ldots + a_l$,      where $a_i \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$     and $a_i \leq z$ for all $i$,
  where $l$ runs from $0$  to $k$.
- The number of ways of throwing
  $x$ indistinguishable balls into $y$ indistinguishable bins, where each bin can contain up to $z$ balls.

Can we write $f$ as a function from $\mathbb Z^3 \to \mathbb Z$ ? probably recursively.? Or represent it somehow combinatorially using some partition function etc.?

**PS**: I am not looking for q-binomial formula because that gives " The number of ways of throwing $x$ **distinguishable** balls into $y$ indistinguishable bins, where each bin can contain up to $z$ balls." Instead, I am asking for "The number of ways of throwing $x$ **indistinguishable** balls into $y$ indistinguishable bins, where each bin can contain up to $z$ balls.
"

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, your $f(x,y,z)$ is a particular coefficient of a $q$-binomial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll rename all three of your variables; you are asking for the number of partitions of $k$ that fit into an $m \times n$ box. This is famously known to be the coefficient of $q^k$ in the [$q$-binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_binomial_coefficient)

$${m+n \choose m}_q = \frac{[m+n]_q!}{[m]_q! [n]_q!}$$

where $[n]_q! = \prod_{i=1}^n \left( \frac{q^i - 1}{q - 1} \right)$ is the $q$-factorial. Much is known about these, including a $q$-analog of Pascal's identity that leads to a recurrence.

Comment: Saying "coefficient of a q-binomial coefficient" is confusing, but accurate.

Comment: Please check the update to the question. I am looking for something else instead of q-binomial formula.

Comment: @MIQ: as far as I can tell, the Wikipedia article is wrong here. The $q$-binomial coefficient counts exactly what you asked for, with the balls indistinguishable. You can double-check some small numbers with the numbers given on MathWorld, for example: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-BinomialCoefficient.html

Comment: For some reason that "distinguishable" has been repeatedly and erroneously edited into the Wiki article on q-binomials. I changed it to "indistinguishable" (who knows how long the change will last, though).

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain a recursion by conditioning on the largest part:
$$f(x,y,z) = \sum_{p \le z} f(x-p,y-1,p)$$